# Show number of factories behind categories in sidebar. codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, join, count, records

I have a sidebar with categories. when i click on one categorie it shows me the factories who are located in that category.

I did this using joins in codeigniter.

Now i want to show how much factories are in a category. so for example:

```
Categories.

Cars (2)
Books (7)
Animals (45)
```

So it simple has to show how much factories have that specific category.

i tried to do a simple count_all_results but then i get the total count of factories. but i want them to count by the specific id of categories.

my model function:

```
function categorieen_getall($segment3)
{
    $this->db->where('categorieen.idcategorieen', $segment3);
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('bedrijfcategorieen');
    $this->db->join('categorieen', 'categorieen.idcategorieen = bedrijfcategorieen.idcategorieen');
    $this->db->join('bedrijven', 'bedrijven.idbedrijven = bedrijfcategorieen.idbedrijven');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result();
    /*
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($result);
    */
    return $result;
}
```

My controller function:

```
    function get_All()
    {
        $data['cat'] = $this->categorieen_model->categorieen_getall($segment3);
        $this->load->view('views/sidebar', $data);
    }
```

My view:

```
    <div id="sidebar">
    <?php
    echo '<h3>Categorieën</h3>';
    echo ($this->db->count_all_results('categorieen')); 

    ?>

        <hr>
        <br/>
        <?php
        echo '<ul>';
        if(isset($cat) && is_array($cat)){
            foreach($links as $k => $value){

                echo '<li>';
                echo '<br>';
                echo '<a href="'.base_url().'home/categorie/'.$value->idcategorieen.' ">' .$value->Categorie. '</a>';
                echo '</li>';

            }
        }
        echo '<ul>';
        /*
        if(isset($cat ) && is_array($cat )){
            foreach($cat as $key => $row){
                echo "Categorie:"; echo $row->Categorie;
                echo "<br />";
                echo $row->idcategorieen;
                echo "<br />";
                echo $row->Bedrijfsnaam;
            }
        }
        */
        ?>
</div>
```

My database scheme:

```
Factories
--------
idfactories
factoryname
adress
email
...

Categories
----------
idcategories
Category


Factorycategories
-----------------
idfactorycategories
idcategories
idfactories
```

Comment: I'm sorry, what exactly is the problem you are encountering?

Comment: i tried to show the number of records who have a specific category. so in my sidebar i have categories. but i want the number of factories behind that like this : Categorie1 (2) where 2 are the factories with that specific category.

Comment: i just did echo ($this->db->count_all_results('bedrijven')); but that show's me all factories as a integer. but i want them for a specific id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked another question. with the same problem and i solved it.

Look at my own answer with the solution i got!

[Count results in joined table and show between () in sidebar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15787419/count-results-in-joined-table-and-show-between-in-sidebar/16316088#16316088)

Thanks for the people who helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not quite suitable because **I know there is a better way to do this**, but this will do the work for you:

```
// Get categories
$categories = array();

$query = $this->db->query("select * from `Categories` order by `idcategories`");

if($query->num_rows() > 0)
{
  foreach($query->result_array() as $row)
  {
    $query_count = $this->db->query("select `idfactorycategories` from `Factorycategories` where `idcategories` = {$row['idcategories']}");
    $factory_count = $query_count->num_rows();

    $categories[] = array(
      'count' => $factory_count 
    );
  }
}
```

For ease, you can first get categories in a `foreach` loop and then for each of them submit a query for the `factories` table to get relevant count of factories with that related category id.

Comment: i have no category row in my factories table. i use a factorycategories table with joined id's. so would that change something?

Comment: I don't know your tables schemes but I think you're able to replace proper code in mine.

Comment: can you explain the line where it says {$row['id']}"); ?

Comment: i can post my database schema above. so maybe it's a bit clearer for you. i'm still new to codeigniter :)

Comment: It gets the current category id that is fetching into `$row` variable. It means we are getting current category id and giving it to the table `factories`.

Comment: see my database scheme above.

Comment: Ok, I'm seeing it now and I'm going to edit my answer to suit the scheme.

Comment: so where do i have to put this? straight onto my view or in my model/controller?

Comment: I usually do the model job in my controllers, you can to the same and you have to put this in your relevant function before where you're going to load categories view. You can use `categories[]` as a data array and pass it to that view. The rest of the work is up to you.

Comment: i can't get it to work. because i don't really understand it.

Comment: you can see how it looks like for now at http://kees.een-site-bouwen.nl look at the left sidebar. it now echo's all the factories. but there are not 8 factories in each category.

Comment: I gave you the idea. You should fit it with your logic.

Comment: Do you know how many SQL queries are executed just for displaying that in your sidebar? If you have N number of categories, you will be calling your DB N+1 times with that foreach loop.

Comment: isn't there a shorter much simplier way?