# Count results in joined table and show between () in sidebar

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, count

I have a sidebar with categories. as you can see here: http://kees.een-site-bouwen.nl/

The id of the category in within the url. with an uri segment(3)
When you click on one of the categories for example webdesign.
some factories are shown. these factories have a join with the categories.
so when the category id = 11, the factories with category id=11 are shown.

***but now i want to show how much factories are in that category. the output will show up between the***

`()` here: http://kees.een-site-bouwen.nl/

So my actual question is: **how do i count_all_results() so it only shows me the factories who are located in the category?**

What i've tried.

```
<?php
if (isset($results) && is_array($results)) { 
foreach ($results as $key => $row) { 
$id = $row->idcategorieen; 
$segment3 = $this->uri->segment(3); 
if ($id == $segment3) { 

echo '<h2>Categorie:', '&nbsp;' , $row->Categorie;  
echo '<h2>';
echo br(1);
echo '<p class="field">';
echo '<h3><label class="field">Aantal:</label></h3>', $this->db->count_all_results('bedrijven');
echo '</p>';
echo br(1); 
break;
} 
}
}
?>
<br />
<h4>Bedrijven</h4>
<hr>
<br />
<?php foreach($results as $item):?>

<p>Bedrijfsnaam: <a href="<?php echo base_url()?>home/showindividueel/<?php echo $item->idbedrijven?>">
<?= $item->Bedrijfsnaam   ?></a><br /></p> 
 </tr>
 <?php endforeach;?>
```

this shows me all of the factories in my database. but i only need the ones in the specific category.

Sidebar code:

```
        echo '<ul>';
        if(isset($cat) && is_array($cat)){
            foreach($links as $k => $value)
                {
                    echo '<li>';
                    echo '<br>';
                    echo '<a href="'.base_url().'home/categorie/'.$value->idcategorieen.' ">' .$value->Categorie. '</a>';
                    echo nbs(1);
                    echo '(';
                    echo ')';
                    echo '</li>';
                }
            }
        echo '<ul>';
```

Thanks.

Comment: post some code for reference.

Comment: posted some code. what exactly do you need?

Comment: Can you post your result array structure where Aantal is generated?

Comment: see my edit. thats the whole file.

Comment: Hi....are you calling it from view..??

Comment: at the moment i do yes. i tried it from controller, but i don't understand how i echo it out to the views then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem using a new function in my controller.

My controller:

```
$data['counts'] = $this->bedrijven_model->bedrijf_categorie();
```

My model:

```
function bedrijf_categorie()
{

    $sql = "
    SELECT count(b.idbedrijven) as ItemCount, c.Categorie as Categorie
    FROM `bedrijven` b
    INNER JOIN `bedrijfcategorieen` bc
    ON bc.idbedrijven = b.idbedrijven
    INNER JOIN `categorieen` c
    ON c.idcategorieen = bc.idcategorieen
    GROUP BY c.idcategorieen
    ";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

my views:

```
    <?php   
    echo '<ul>';
            foreach($counts as $count){

                    echo '<li>';
                    echo '<a href="'.base_url().'home/categorieen/'.$count['Categorie'].' ">' .$count['Categorie']. '</a>';
                    echo nbs(1);
                    echo '(';
                    echo $count['ItemCount'];
                    echo ')';
                    echo '</li>';
                }
    echo '</ul>';
    ?>
```

Anyway. thanks people who helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
echo '<h3><label class="field">Aantal:</label></h3>', $this->db->count_all_results('bedrijven');
```

with following

```
echo '<h3><label class="field">Aantal:</label></h3>', count($results);
```

Comment: allright that's step one. but now i would like to show it in the sidebar. i add my sidebar code above.

Comment: I think you are not getting even $results..right..??I have just seen your site

Comment: look at http://kees.een-site-bouwen.nl/home/categorie/11 i see the results. but i want them on the mainpage where the sidebar is. and not on the category page.

Comment: i need to add the if(isset($results) to the sidebar?

Comment: yes ofcourse but the better option is to claa the db functions at the controller itself where you have load the dashboard view

Comment: and i don't think it's possible because it uses the url for showing the results.

Comment: just look at http://kees.een-site-bouwen.nl/home/categorie/ without a id behind the url no factories are shown. so that way does not work for me.