# get the number of factories that are in a category

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, count, categories

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15758599/show-number-of-factories-behind-categories-in-sidebar-codeigniter) question, I asked about how to show the number of factories which are located in a specific category (using count).

I just want to do something like this:

```
Sidebar
------
Category1 (3)
Category2 (7)
Category3 (2)
```

where the number between the () are the factories which are located in a specific category.

I use a joined table to get the factoryid and categoryid. I called this table factorycategories. In this way, I can specify more than one category for my factories.

So how do I count those factories with the category id?

I can get it work when I use the id in the url, but on the index page, I don't have id's in my url so that won't work.

My table structure:

```
factorycategories
-----------------
idfactorycategories
idfactories
idcategories

factories
---------
idfactories
factoryname
adress
postcode
country
etc etc..

categories
----------
idcategories
category
```

## edit

My current code:

factories model:

```
function bedrijf_categorie()
{

    $sql = "
    SELECT count(b.idbedrijven) as ItemCount, c.Categorie as Categorie
    FROM `bedrijven` b
    INNER JOIN `bedrijfcategorieen` bc
    ON bc.idbedrijven = b.idbedrijven
    INNER JOIN `categorieen` c
    ON c.idcategorieen = bc.idcategorieen
    GROUP BY c.idcategorieen
    ";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->result();
}

    function index()
    {
    $data['counts'] = $this->bedrijven_model->bedrijf_categorie();
    }
```

in my views:

```
print_r($counts)
```

## edit2

fixed it. i deleted

```
foreach($query as $k->$value){
```

this was my old function.

and added

```
foreach($counts as $count){
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your model you would need to adjust your query. I am not sure exactly what your table structure looks like, so I am using my own example:

```
SELECT count(c.id) as ItemCount, p.shortname as Page
FROM `icms3_content` c
INNER JOIN `icms3_page_content` pc
ON pc.content_id = c.id
INNER JOIN `icms3_page` p
ON p.id = pc.page_id
GROUP BY p.id
```

This brings the result for me as follows:

```
ItemCount | Page
===========================
        2 | home
        1 | typography
        1 | responsive
```

This is the correct result, as the home page has two pieces of content, and the other 2 pages has only one item each.

Below is my table structures:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `icms3_content` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `teaser` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `content` longtext NOT NULL,
  `author` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `active` enum('Yes','No') NOT NULL,
  `publish_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `unpublish_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `icms3_page` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `shortname` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `keywords` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(320) NOT NULL,
  `author` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `icms3_page_content` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `page_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `content_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ;
```

**EDIT: Your query will change to the following, using your posted tables:**

```
SELECT count(f.id) as ItemCount, c.category as Category
FROM `factories` f
INNER JOIN `factorycategories` fc
ON fc.idfactories = f.idfactories
INNER JOIN `categories` c
ON c.idcategories = fc.idcategories
GROUP BY c.idcategories
```

Comment: posted my table structure. please edit your question if you could.

Comment: hm i added the code but i can't get a result. what do i have to put in my controller and views? @Kobus

Comment: it now only gives me the factories in the first category. but i want them for all my categories. maybe i am doin something wrong.

Comment: @KeesSonnema, your controller will simply call a model function with the query that returns the result array (return $q->result_array, where $q is the query object), and in your view you will simply loop through the array of values. Please paste your code as you currently have it, so I can check what you're doing wrong.

Comment: i can see the item counts for two categories (the other categories are empty) but how can i show tehm 1 by 1 for each categorie? stdClass Object ( [ItemCount] => 2 [Categorie] => Webdesign ) stdClass Object ( [ItemCount] => 2 [Categorie] => Vlaggen )

Comment: i fixed it i deleted my older function to show categories and added the new one (yours) i linked it using uri segment. now it's working! awesome.

Answer (score 0):

you just looking for something like this

```
   select count(Factorycategories.idfactorycategories) as total , Factorycategories.idcategories, Categories.Category from Factorycategories 

LEFT JOIN Categories
ON Factorycategories.idcategories=Categories.idcategories

group by Factorycategories.idcategories


idfactorycategories idcategories    idfactories
        1              1                1
        2                  1                2
        3              2                3
        4              3                4
        5              1                5
```

you just have to fetch category name with left join or with sample join to print category name from category table

**Output**

```
total   idcategories
3            1
1            2
1            3
```

Comment: this is not working because i don't know how to implement this. also look at the other question in top of my question. there are the tables and functions better explained.

Comment: pls check my updated query if you have table like your previous question

Comment: so could i now just add a function to the controller and then view that in the view so the factories were shown as a number behind my categories?

Comment: yes but you have to add left join query in above sql query so you can see category name

Comment: so how do i do that? sorry but i'm not that familiar with mysql queries.

Comment: i get an sql error. could you do the same with ci's active record?

Comment: sorry i am not so familiar with CI you should have to manage :(

Comment: here's the error. http://kees.een-site-bouwen.nl/ on the main page. you can look at it.

Comment: just click on the category 'auto-s' that category is empty but it shows me 2 http://kees.een-site-bouwen.nl/